# Errors have been found during processing: ssl-cert

Tags: package-management, 22.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu version to 22.04. Every time I try to install a package I get this error.

[image]

Comment: Are you having enough free disk space?? Please include output of `df -h`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.